# How to parse dynamic JSON with Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I'm trying to parse JSON where same field can be either array or object. Same as, specific field can be either string or number. Please consider examples below.

1. Empty object

```
{
 "technicalData": {}
}
```

2. Collection with field being either string or number

```
{
 "technicalData": [
   { 
      "techValueString": "0.173"
   },
   { 
      "techValueString": 0.173
   }
 ]
}
```

How can I do it with Circe mapping to Scala classes accepting Nil when data is {}?

```
case class Response(technicalData: Seq[TechnicalData])

case class TechnicalData(techValueString: String)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you retrieve any `techValueString` from case 1 (json object) ? Don't you have a non empty object example?

Comment: @BenjaminVialatou this is the same JSON, it's done bad (third party). If no "technicalData" then it will be presented as JsObject {} (case #1), otherwise fields will be included in collection (case #2). Basically it very customised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really verbose way of resolving your problem but I hope it has the advantage of letting you identify, or even rectify, every limit cases, which you might need:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser.parse

case class Response(technicalData: Seq[TechnicalData])

case class TechnicalData(techValueString: String)

val stringAsJson1 = """{

 "technicalData": {}
}"""

val stringAsJson2 = """{
 "technicalData": [
   { 
      "techValueString": "0.173"
   },
   { 
      "techValueString": 0.173
   }
 ]
}"""


def manageTechnicalDataAsArray(jsonArray: Vector[io.circe.Json]): Response = {
    Response(
      jsonArray.map(cell => {
        val value = cell.asObject
                        .getOrElse(throw new Exception("technicalData as a array should have each cell as an object"))
                        .apply("techValueString")
                        .getOrElse(throw new Exception("techValueString should be a key of any cell under technicalData array"))
        TechnicalData(value.asNumber
                           .map(_.toString)
                           .getOrElse(
                            value.asString
                                 .getOrElse(throw new Exception("techValueString value should be either string or number"))
                           )
                     )
                     }
               )
             )
}

def manageTechnicalDataAsObject(jsonObject: io.circe.JsonObject): Response = {
    jsonObject.toIterable match {
         case empty if empty.isEmpty => Response(Nil)
         case _ => throw new Exception("technicalData when object should be empty")
    }
}

def parseResponse(jsonAsString: String): Response = {
    parse(jsonAsString).getOrElse(Json.Null)
                       .asObject
                       .map(_("technicalData")
                             .getOrElse(throw new Exception("the json should contain a technicalData key"))
                             .arrayOrObject(throw new Exception("technicalData should contain either an objet or array"),
                                            manageTechnicalDataAsArray,
                                            manageTechnicalDataAsObject
                             )
                       ).getOrElse(throw new Exception("the json should contain an object at top"))
}

println(parseResponse(stringAsJson1))
println(parseResponse(stringAsJson2))
```

I might come with a shorter version soon but less indicative on limit cases. You can explore them with tweaked version of a good json of yours.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Here is a shorter and cleaner solution than above, which come after @Sergey Terentyev well found one. Well, it might be less readeable somehow, but it tends to do the same thing with more or less way to handle limit cases:

```
  // Structure part
  case class TechnicalData(techValueString: String)
  object TechnicalData {
    def apply[T](input: T) = new TechnicalData(input.toString)
  }

  case class Response(technicalData: Seq[TechnicalData])

  // Decoding part
  import io.circe.{Decoder, parser, JsonObject, JsonNumber}
  import io.circe.Decoder.{decodeString, decodeJsonNumber}

  def tDDGenerator[C : Decoder]: Decoder[TechnicalData] = Decoder.forProduct1("techValueString")(TechnicalData.apply[C])

  implicit val technicalDataDecoder: Decoder[TechnicalData] = tDDGenerator[String].or(tDDGenerator[JsonNumber])

  implicit val responseDecoder: Decoder[Response] = Decoder[JsonObject]
    .emap(_("technicalData").map(o => Right(o.as[Seq[TechnicalData]].fold(_ => Nil, identity)))
      .getOrElse(Right(Nil))
      .map(Response.apply))

  // Test part

  val inputStrings = Seq(
    """{
      | "technicalData": [
      |   {
      |      "techValueString": "0.173"
      |   },
      |   {
      |      "techValueString": 0.173
      |   }
      | ]
      |}
  """.stripMargin,
    """{
      | "technicalData": {}
      |}
  """.stripMargin
  )

  inputStrings.foreach(parser.decode[Response](_).fold(println,println))
```

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. I will try to adapt to my solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is less verbose solution applying Circe's Decoders

```scala
case class Response(technicalData: Seq[TechnicalData])

case class TechnicalData(techValueString: String)

class StringToResponse() extends (String => Response) {

  implicit val responseDecoder: Decoder[Response] = Decoder.instance { c =>
    for {
      technicalData <- c.downField("technicalData").focus match {
        case None => Right(Nil)
        case Some(seq) => seq.asArray match {
          case None => Right(Nil)
          case Some(_) => c.get[Seq[TechnicalData]]("technicalData")
        }
      }
    } yield {
      Response(technicalData)
    }
  }

  implicit val technicalDataDecoder: Decoder[TechnicalData] = (
    Decoder.instance(_.get[String]("techValueString")).or(
      Decoder.instance(_.get[Double]("techValueString").map(_.toString))
    )
  ) mapN TechnicalData

  override def apply(body: String): Response = {
    decode[Response](body) match {
      case Right(response) => response
      case Left(e) => throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help someone who would come across similar problem.

Comment: Well done @Sergey Terentyev ! I see you want `Nil` when no `"technicalData"` key. I didn't really know about `instance` and `focus` actually so I can learn from that. I've made some search on my side and started to make up another solution. Well, I could share it with you soon in my answer.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, 
Indeed normally you should not call "Decoder.instance" explicitly if you using in it in for yield body. But I found it quite handy :) With focus you can determine whether field is present or not. 
Thanks for your help.